# Display / Browser resolutions

Tags: windows, resolution, scaling

On a Lenovo thinkpad 15", I have a resolution of 1920x1080.
Windows 10 recommends a 125% scaling on the laptop screen.

I expected a screen-width (in pixels) of 1536px but this system gives me only 1024px width.

I checked other setups (exernal monitor on a HP laptop), same resolution, they give 100% recommended. When switching to 125%, i still have the 1536px width.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you get 1536px? How did you measure this? Scaling doesn't change the monitor's resolution.

Comment: no but we noticed the problem with a responsive website. I 'measured' the horizontal pixels in chrome ... which is 1536 on my system, the faulty one only has 1024px available.

Peronally i think that the dpi range of the lcd's differ giving this result? Or something else?

Comment: It could be software (different browser versions, OS, drivers, ...) or hardware (different monitor, GPU, ...). It's very hard to say at this point.